# how to transform point at origin with transformation matrix

Tags: c++, transformation

I want to transform a `vector(0,0,0)` to a new point with the transformation matrix but if you do the transformation [matrix * v] you would end up at `vector(0,0,0)` every time. I am thinking there is an added step that I need to do for this to end up working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming 3D zero-vector with a 3x3 matrix will always result in the zero-vector because 3x3 matrices can only represent linear transforms. But translations are not linear. Therefore, you need to use homogeneous coordinates and a 4x4 matrix. If you have a 4x4 translation matrix, you need to add `1` as the fourth dimension to the vector, so it will get `(0, 0, 0, 1)` and transform this with your matrix. If the matrix is just a translation (or in general an affine transform), you just need to cut off the fourth dimension to get the final 3D vector.